# How to split pandas columns according to some rule, and sum up the values

Tags: pandas

I have columns that are values `2/300/3` like this, but I want some of this value, in this case, `2+300+3=305`. In order to achieve this goal I am using the command

```
for i in range(len(df.col)):
    df.col.iloc[i]=sum([float(j) for j in df.col.iloc[i].split("|")])
```

The length of this data frame is big, that why the above command is very time-consuming.
Does there exist another way to do the same operation without loop?
NOTE: the number of "/" is not fixed and in some cases it does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` and `eval` can do the job

```
import pandas as pd

data = ["2/300/3" , "5/300/3" , "3 50 3"]

df =pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["data"])

df["total_sum"] = df["data"].str.replace('[/ |" "]','+').apply(pd.eval)
```

Output:

```
    data    total_sum
0   2/300/3 305
1   5/300/3 308
2   3 50 3  56
```

Comment: It gives me the error 'AttributeError: 'PandasExprVisitor' object has no attribute 'visit_Ellipsis''

Answer (score 0):

you can also use str.split and apply

```
import pandas as pd
data = ["2/300/3" , "5/300/3" , "3/50/3"]
df =pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["data"])
df.data = df.data.str.split('/').apply(lambda x: sum(map(int,x)))
```